# How do I iterate through text fields and push the value to an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a script that iterates through the form and stores the values into an array on keypress. The array is then displayed as concatenated text in another form called 'resultBox'. When i try to access using the document.GetElementById method it is giving  uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null.

```
var values = [];

function getKeys(){
    for(var i = 0; i<myForm.length; i++){
        console.log(myForm[i].value);
        var txtValue = document.getElementById(myForm).value;
        values.push(txtValue);
        console.log(values);
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Excercise 2</title>
    <script src ="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        input[type=text] {
                width: 50%;
                padding: 12px 20px;
                margin: 8px 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="txt1">Text Box 1</label>
        <input type = "text" onkeyup = 'getKeys()'id='txt1' name="txt1"> <br><br>
        <label for="txt2">Text Box 2</label>
        <input type = "text" id='txt2' name="txt2"><br><br>
        <label for="txt3">Text Box 3</label>
        <input type = "text" id='txt3' name="txt3"><br><br>
        <label for="txt4">Text Box 4</label>
        <input type = "text" id='txt4' name="txt4"><br><br>
        <label for="txt5">Text Box 5</label>
        <input type = "text" id='txt5' name="txt5"><br><br>
        <label for="txt6">Text Box 6</label>
        <input type = "text" id='txt6' name="txt6"><br><br>
    </form>
    <form id ="resultBox">
        <label for="txtResult">Result Box</label>
        <input type = "text" id ="txtResult" name="txtResult" readonly><br><br>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using some built-in methods like `querySelectorAll()`, `map()`, `filter()` and `join()` like the following way:

```js
var inputList = document.querySelectorAll('#myForm [type=text]:not(#txt6)');
inputList.forEach(function(input){
  input.addEventListener('input', function(){
    var values = Array.from(inputList).map(el => el.value.trim()).filter(v => v).join(', ');
    document.getElementById('txtResult').value = values;
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="txt1">Text Box 1</label>
  <input type = "text" id='txt1' name="txt1"> <br><br>
  <label for="txt2">Text Box 2</label>
  <input type = "text" id='txt2' name="txt2"><br><br>
  <label for="txt3">Text Box 3</label>
  <input type = "text" id='txt3' name="txt3"><br><br>
  <label for="txt4">Text Box 4</label>
  <input type = "text" id='txt4' name="txt4"><br><br>
  <label for="txt5">Text Box 5</label>
  <input type = "text" id='txt5' name="txt5"><br><br>
  <label for="txt6">Text Box 6</label>
  <input type = "text" id='txt6' name="txt6"><br><br>
</form>
<form id ="resultBox">
  <label for="txtResult">Result Box</label>
  <input type = "text" id ="txtResult" name="txtResult" readonly> <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I should have noted that I have to add a button that adds another text field and doesnt break the code. Is there a way I could use a for loop and the .length property to achieve this. Along with the querySelectorAll() method or the getElementByID method.

Comment: @BenMarr, it does not matter how many text inputs are there in the from, the code will work for all the text input elements as long as they are inside the form:)

Comment: I have tried using the code you provided but the result box stays empty after i type something into the text field.